# How to get file extension with expo FileSystem?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using expo FileSystem to get photos and videos from cameraRoll. is there any way to get these files extensions?

Answer (score 5):

## Using ImagePicker

If you have asked for permission and are able to get a response from the ImagePicker you should get an object that looks like this.

```
{
  "cancelled": false,
  "height": 2436,
  "type": "image",
  "uri": "file:///lots/of/directories/where/the/image/is/stored/ImagePicker/B69EA641-4738-4425-8319-FE190FC4BD6D.png",
  "width": 1125,
}
```

If you call the ImagePicker like this (remember this is an `await` so it should be wrapped in a `try/catch`)

```
let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({mediaTypes:'Images'});
```

You can then access the uri by using `result.uri`

So we can do something like this

```
let uri = result.uri;
let fileExtension = uri.substr(uri.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
```

Remember the user can cancel the request so you should check the `result.cancelled` is false before trying to get the file extension, otherwise you will have issues as the uri will not exist.

## Using CameraRoll

The responses from using the Camera Roll aren't consistent across platforms. The following code will access the first video on the device.

```
let params = { first: 1, assetType: CameraRoll.AssetTypeOptions.Videos }; 
let result = await CameraRoll.getPhotos(params)
let videos = result.edges // the edges key stores an array of objects
```

#### Android

```
{
  node: {
    group_name: 0,
    image:  {
      height: 1280,
      playableDuration: 56,
      uri: "content://media/external/video/media/125",
      width: 720,
    },
    timestamp: 1541516873,
    type: "video/mp4",
  },
}
```

### iOS

```
{
  node:  {
    group_name: "Camera Roll",
    image:  {
      filename: "IMG_5030.MOV",
      height: 1080,
      isStored: true,
      playableDuration: 612,
      uri: "assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=10711D3D-EBDC-4EF2-A849-411D593A0B15&ext=MOV",
      width: 1920,
    },
    location:  {
      altitude: 0,
      heading: -1,
      latitude: 0.0,
      longitude: 0.0,
      speed: -1,
    },
    timestamp: 1544786625,
    type: "ALAssetTypeVideo",
  },
}
```

As you can see `Android` doesn't give a specific `filename`, unlike `iOS` which does. For `iOS` you can extract the file extension using the method I described above. Unfortunately for `Android` the only way to get the actual file extension is to use the `ImagePicker`.

Comment: thanks for reply, but i've used CameraRoll like this:
let params = { first: 21, assetType: CameraRoll.AssetTypeOptions.Videos };
CameraRoll.getPhotos(params)
i wanted to implement something like instagram adding post does.
but it seems like in android there nothing like including file extension in cameraRoll api

Comment: Yeah that's why I explained using the ImagePicker. CameraRoll is a little limited in what it returns on Android. I've updated my answer to include the differences between iOS and Android responses.